# Is it Possible to Run Shell Script in Browser

Tags: java, html

Sorry if you are thinking this as Basic question. I am Having shell scripts which accepts Some parameters as Inputs to Run the Script.

Is it Possible to Pass these Parameters through **Web form** and Run the Shell script through Browser.

How to implement this using java if Possible. or any other technology is Best.

Thanks in Advance. Looking forward for your valuable Advice's.

**Edit:-**

Hi All,

Currently I am having  an GUI which runs Scripts on Client Computer by accepting Some parameters. I want to keep those Shell Scripts on Server and Run by passing parameters using Web form. Sorry if my language is difficult to understand.

Comment: This is a security risk whether you take client input and run on the server or the other way around. It may be possible to run server-side, but certainly not on the client.

Comment: "Run the Shell script through Browser"?? Script runs on the client side or server side? Client side -- NO. Server side-- Yes but its still bad to pass parameters to it.

Comment: It is possible when you use a Java applet but I think it's a terrible idea (security!). Why do you want to do that? Also, web applications should generally abstract from the OS and even the browser used by the client.

Comment: do you want like : run shell script on shell via your java program while parameters and script are from web form?

Comment: Where are you shell scripts? Client or server? Are we basically talking about CGI here?

Comment: Why is this question at -7? It's a valid question. It lacks details, but you can answer it properly right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a Java Applet with heightened security privileges and a JavaScript API so that JavaScript in the page could read the form data and pass it to the applet. The client computer would need to have the Java plugin and whatever shell you were using installed, and the user would have to accept the above-normal-security-level access rights the applet asked for.

This isn't in the least bit practical for the WWW and is rather a stretch for a controlled network.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script using a signed applet.